# Как упростить проверку на null на C#?

Tags: c#

Есть ли возможность упростить такое выражение:

```
if (locker != null)
{
    locker.ReadLock();
}
```

В такое или подобное, используя новый сахар в языке C#?

```
locker??locker.ReadLock();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавился [специальный *Null-conditional* оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

```
locker?.ReadLock();
```

Comment: +1, можете еще пояснить отличия между ним и null-коалесцирующим оператором (как у автора в вопросе).

Comment: @Nikita, не совсем понял: различие вообще, или в том примере что в вопросе приведен: `locker??locker.ReadLock();` vs `locker?.ReadLock();`?

Comment: Возможность короче записать

Comment: @nick_n_a, не понял комментарий :-)

Comment: @Grundy разница между ними _вообще_ будет весьма кстати, потому что из вопроса (в частности, приведенного примера там) следует, что автор не понимает, когда использовать ??, а когда ?. , поэтому кроме семантического отличия можно описать что во что разворачивается, какой из них является потокобезопасным, а какой нет (по мне это весьма важно) ну и т.д.

Comment: Этот оператор также называют `elvis-operator` в англоязычных источниках. Если можно, добавьте в ответ.

Comment: Мой пример вообщето не компилируется так как ?? только в присвоении работает, а не в вызове void функций.